# java concurrency in practice 16.7

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

This code is used to demonstrate double-checked-locking anti-pattern:

```
@NotThreadSafe
public class DoubleCheckedLocking {
    private static Resource resource;

    public static Resource getInstance() {
        if (resource == null) {
            synchronized (DoubleCheckedLocking.class) {
                if (resource == null)
                    resource = new Resource();
            }
        }
        return resource;
    }
}
```

**Can I just avoid this problem by modify it to:**

```
@NotThreadSafe
public class DoubleCheckedLocking {
    private static Resource resource;

    public static Resource getInstance() {
        if (resource == null) {
            synchronized (DoubleCheckedLocking.class) {
                if (resource == null){
                    Resource r=new Resource();
                    resource = r;
                }
            }
        }
        return resource;
    }
}
```

As far as I know,

```
Resource r=new Resource();
resource = r;
```

That compiler should provide happen-before relationship for that.

Comment: Although this is not the standard pattern, your question was interesting (I think your proposed modification makes sense and does solve the issue). It would have been great to leave it open a little to get more specific answers.

Comment: What exactly does the book say is wrong with the example?

Comment: @ninjalj The main issue with the first idiom is not the risk of having the resource created twice, but the risk of returning a reference to a partially constructed object. In the second example, there still is a risk of having a resource constructed twice, but I think the possibility of seeing a partially constructed object has been removed.

Comment: @assylias: no, it isn't removed. The thread that sees `resource != null` has not executed any synchronization (possibly implying CPU and/or compiler barriers) to wait for visibility of things `resource` depends on.

Comment: While you have `happens-before` for the thread creating the `resource`, you don't have `synchronizes-with` between that and the thread reading the `resource`.

Comment: @ninjalj Reference assignment is atomic, so in the second example, either resource is seen as null, or it is seen as non null and points to a fully constructed object. Your argument (if I understand well) is to say that in the second case, the state (fields) of the resource might not be fully visible and the object might be *seen* as partially constructed by another thread?

Comment: @assylias: the reference assignment _itself_ is atomic, e.g: you won't end up with half a reference, but the constructed object may not be visible to other threads just yet, that may require barriers.

Comment: @ninjalj Yes I agree - upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the only known implementation of the double-checked locking pattern that works (for JDK5 and above) makes use of the 'volatile' keyword. [See Fixing Double-Checked Locking using Volatile](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html)

Comment: That does not really answer the question.

Comment: I reopen this thread to allow people to discuss.
I'll accept later.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Resource getInstance() {
    if (resource == null) {
        synchronized (DoubleCheckedLocking.class) {
            if (resource == null){
                Resource r=new Resource();
                resource = r;
            }
        }
    }
    return resource;
}
```

The only thing that guarantees proper visibility between threads is creating *synchronizes-with* relationships via synchronization (via `synchronized`, `volatile`, ...).

If you don't have a *synchronizes-with* relationship, a thread is not required to see modifications from other threads.

In this case, a thread may create a `Resource` and store a reference to it in `resource`. Then a second thread may enter `getInstance()`, and see `resource != null`. This second thread is not guaranteed to see all the effects of `resource`'s constructions, since it isn't *synchronized-with* the first thread.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is allowed to optimise:

```
Resource r=new Resource();
resource = r;
```

to

```
resource=new Resource();
```

so your adjustment is ineffective.